# Joomla 3.5 Feedback Survey

Tags: discussion

Maybe off-topic, but wanted to share with everyone. 
I guess feedback from users will help Joomla improve.

The JUX team has a new survey specifically for Joomla 3.5. You can take the survey here: http://bit.ly/1VOoz1H.

The Joomla UX Team is collecting feedback on the recent Joomla 3.5 release. By providing your feedback, you are  participating in the Joomla community and helping us to improve future versions of Joomla!

This survey is mostly multiple choice answers and should take around 10 minutes to complete, you are free to spend more time providing personal feedback if you choose to, but it is not required, nor is any directly personal information.

Comment: Nice one. Submitted my feedback